# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mollie\Api\Endpoints\SubscriptionEndpoint::update() in Wordpress plugin for WebhookUrl update

Tags: php, wordpress, mollie, easy-digital-downloads

I'm trying to update the webhookUrl in mollie for a subscription. The old webhookUrl is outdated and the programmer who made it is no longer with us.

This is the [link of mollie](https://docs.mollie.com/reference/v2/subscriptions-api/update-subscription) that I'm trying to use. After checking the new version on [github](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php) I saw that the method to [update a subscription](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php/blob/master/examples/subscriptions/update-subscription.php) is a little different. Even though the differences, I still get an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mollie\Api\Endpoints\SubscriptionEndpoint::update()

This is the code I made to make a form out of it. I am attempting to change the webhookUrl to connect to Easy digital Downloads so that the subscriptions and licenses don't expire because the payment can't be checked.

Form(admin__update_subscription.php):

```
<form id="wmcs-form" method="post">
    <div class="wmcs_admin_card">
        <div class="wmcs_admin_body">
            <fieldset class="choose-theme-wrap radio-boxes dp-tabular">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Customer id</label>
                        <input type="text" id="customer_id" name="customer_id" value="" required>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Subscription id</label>
                        <input type="text" id="subscription_id" name="subscription_id" value="" required>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Webhook URL</label>
                        <input type="text" id="webhook_url" name="webhook_url" value="" required>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="button-primary" name="mollie_update_subscription">Change</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset><!-- End of choose-theme-wrap -->    
        </div><!-- End of wmcs_admin_body -->
    </div><!-- End of wmcs_admin_card -->
</form>
```

Form handler:

```
public function change_subscription(){ ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['mollie_update_subscription'])){
                if(!empty($_POST['customer_id']) && !empty($_POST['subscription_id'])){
                    $customer_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['customer_id']);
                    $subscription_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['subscription_id']);
                    $webhook_url = sanitize_text_field($_POST['webhook_url']);
                    // $orderID = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_id']);
                    // $orderKey = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_key']);

                    echo $this->mollie_update_subscription($customer_id, $subscription_id, $webhook_url);
                }
            }
        ?>
        <h2><?php _e('Change Subscription URL'); ?></h2>
        <div id="Features" class="wmcs-tabs">
            <?php
                require_once('admin__update_subscription.php');
            ?>
        </div> <!-- End of Settings -->
        <?php
    }
```

Mollie update request:

```
public function mollie_update_subscription($customer_id, $subscription_id, $webhook_url){
        $mollie = new \Mollie\Api\MollieApiClient();
        $mollie->setApiKey(MOLLIE_KEY);(defined elsewhere)

        $message = "";
        try {
            $customer = $mollie->customers->get($customer_id);
            $subscription = $customer->getSubscription($subscription_id);

            $subscription->webhookUrl = $webhook_url;
            $subscription->description = 'subscription update success';
            
            $mollie->subscriptions->update();

            $message = "<p>Subscription updated: " . $subscription->id . "</p>";
        } catch (\Mollie\Api\Exceptions\ApiException $e) {
            $message = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>API call failed: " . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()).'</div>';
        }
        return $message;
    }
```

Any idea's what I'm missing? I was hoping this will update the webhookUrl so that payments will be automatically connected to the subscription on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I needed to change this part:

`$mollie->subscriptions->update();`

to

`$subscription->update();`